# Is there a way to automatically disable Resharper analysis and corrections for #regions in C#?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm cleaning up code that hasn't been refactored for years.  One problem is that there are source files where there is a mix of user code and tool-generated tool.  If Resharper corrects  code (such as replacing types with vars) then the Designer for the tool-generated code (in a #region) breaks.

Is there any way I can set Resharper to ignore certain regions automatically?  I've got a lot of tool-generated code so I don't really want to go through and manually bracket the regions like:

```
#region ActiveReports Designer generated code
//...
#endregion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can customize the regions to ignore in `Resharper` tab => `Options` and from there `Generated Code` under `Code Inspection` :

[image]

You can customize your generated code regions from the panel on the right. Simply click the green `+` button and type the full region name, including the "generated code" part (e.g. ActiveReports Designer generated code)

Please note there will still be an analysis being done in order to provide code completion and error information.

Comment: does the generated code option actually work for someone, when using code cleanup? It does not for me in R# 8.2.